# Deviation chart in base graphics

Tags: r, plot

I need to do a deviance chart (lollipop chart with lines from the mean to values above / below the mean). From this question and answer [Drawing line segments in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192929/drawing-line-segments-in-r), it is clear that I need to plot `segments` and then add the points. However, my x axis is a factor and the solution fails.

This works:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3),
                 score = c(30, 42, 48))
mid <- mean(df$score)

plot(range(df$ID), range(df$score),type="n")
segments(df$ID, df$score, df$ID, mid)
```

But changing my identifier variable into a factor breaks it.

```
df$ID2 <- factor(df$ID)
plot(range(df$ID2), range(df$score),type="n")
segments(df$ID2, df$score, df$ID2, mid)
```

How can I set up the plot area and x-axis values to deal with a factor?

Note that I need a base graphics solution to fit with the other charts in a dashboard style report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the factor in a numeric variable, supress the x-axis and then add the correct labels to the plot:

```
df$ID2 <- factor(letters[df$ID]) # Use letters to show that this is working

plot(range(as.numeric(df$ID2)), range(df$score), type = "n", xaxt = "n")
segments(as.numeric(df$ID2), df$score, as.numeric(df$ID2), mid)
axis(1, at = seq_along(levels(df$ID2)), labels = levels(df$ID2))
```

[image]