# Plotting Line Segments from Coordinates

Tags: r

I want to plot line segments. Each line has a starting point (x1/y1) and ending point (x2/y2). I am following this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192929/drawing-line-segments-in-r), but it does not work. I just get an empty plot:

[image: empty plot, without line segments]

Here the commands I used:

```
data <- matrix(1:12, ncol = 4, dimnames = list(c("a","b","c"), c("x1","y1","x2","y2")))
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,15), ylim=c(0,15), xlab="x", ylab="y")
segments(data["x1"], data["y1"], data["x2"], data["y2"])
```

`data` gives:

```
  x1 y1 x2 y2
a  1  4  7 10
b  2  5  8 11
c  3  6  9 12
```

Later I plan to load data from a text file (`csv`). But for this first test I'm just using this generated nonsensical numbers.

Since I don't get error messages, I'm stuck here. Which basic error have I made? Thank you for your help.

I use:

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree"
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Comment: it is base R matrix, so you need to do segments(data[,"x1"], data[,"y1"], data[,"x2"], data[,"y2"])

Comment: this draws just one line (instead of all). Is it that I should not use a matrix for the coordinates?

Comment: hmmm... or all lines are overlapping on the same line? omg, let me check that :-)

Comment: I replaced `1:12` with other numbers like e.g. `c(1,1,5,5,6,6,12,12,8,8,3,3)` in the `matrix` function. It works nice now. Was not a good idea to just count from one to twelve for test data.

Comment: so all's good with the segment function?

Comment: yes, just the missing commas and bad example data. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As StupidWolf says in the comments, there are missing commas for the matrix. Correct is:

```
segments(data[,"x1"], data[,"y1"], data[,"x2"], data[,"y2"])
```

**But:** You can load `csv` data directly into a data frame and then plot it. Matrix not needed.

[image]

Sample data in a file called `data.csv`:

```
x1,y1,x2,y2
1,1,5,7
6,4,12,10
8,2,3,9
```

Commands:

```
data=read.csv("data.csv", sep=",")
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,15), ylim=c(0,15), xlab="x", ylab="y")
segments(data$x1, data$y1, data$x2, data$y2)
```